# PHP - Tried to allocate 2.5GB?

Tags: php

Need suggestions on how to troubleshoot this...

I'm getting this error message intermittently, starting a few weeks ago:

```
[Tue Dec 22 13:44:54 2015] [error] [client 186.39.132.55] 
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted
(tried to allocate 2811956481 bytes) in ...
```

What's really puzzling to me is how big the attempted allocation is (2.5GB??).  This is during a set of require_once/include_once calls that hasn't changed in years.  No DB calls, no big arrays of data, no files read into memory.

Max memory is currently set at 256M.  The server has 4GB total.

APC Version 3.1.15-dev, 128MB shared memory

PHP Version 5.4.45

Comment: Big file, trapped loop? Without seeing the file that caused the problem that's as much as I can suggest for you.

Comment: Nope.  Call sequence is basically:
front controller.php -> require(a) -> require(b) -> require(c) -> Error.

Comment: At a guess something in that third include is doing a hell of a lot more than you expected.

Comment: Nope.  That third include is less than 100 lines of code.  This error occurs only after the code's been running for a day or two, handling thousands of requests without a problem.
If we graceful apache (which also flushes APC), then it works fine again, for another day or two.

Comment: Ah, now that was what we call pertinent information. You should have put that in the question. I could make more guesses but clearly I do not have all the facts.

Comment: I did try - "intermittently" and "hasn't changed in years" point in that direction.  Also thought I was pretty clear about having ruled out resource dependencies (DB, arrays, files).

Comment: Something has changed. Either PHP version, DB version, Apache version or the files have been compromised.

Answer (score 1):

After some time with Google ([Google is your friend](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=PHP%20Version%205.4.45%20%22memory%20leak%22)) I found that [5.4.45 has a memory leak issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70458). Given what you have said about the files not changing in a long time my money would be on this being the problem.

I imagine the issue started when you upgraded last.

**What can you do?**

1. Downgrade: Not optimal and sometimes a lot of fuss, but it is an option.
2. Upgrade some more. According to the error log this issue has been fixed in later versions.
3. Put up with it and just give the system as much memory as it wants (***a very bad idea***).
4. Set a cron to restart Apache at off-peak times. (A dirty hack, but workable).

Comment: That bug was specifically in the `expect` extension, which the OP doesn't mention using…

Comment: Boom.  This is the kind of thing I was looking for.  Honestly tried the Google but didn't find that, so thanks!  We do currently have the ugly crontab-ed graceful to keep the wheels on.  Will look into which extensions we're using and if an upgrade would be helpful.

Comment: @duskwuff True, although 5.3 and 5.4 do, in certain edge cases, have memory leak issues. It's a bit of an inductive conclusion but the odds are...